# Calculating distance when location is "off road"

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

Is there a way to have Google Distance Matrix API return the closest drive-able location when the current location picked is not?

A little background: During the quoting process, I need to calculate an estimated freight charge to an expected shipment location.

The end goal is a real time distance calculation using the address input by the person generating the quotation. However, this is currently handled by using a database of postal codes, with mileage to each of our plants. For example :

```
| START | END   | DIST  |
-------------------------
| 47601 | 47715 | 29725 |
| 47601 | 47716 | 31741 |
```

This data is old, so I've been tasked with updating it until we can roll out the interactive version.

I'm using the Google Maps Distance Matrix (successfully) to update many of the distances. However I've come across something I can't seem to hash out via code changes. When the postal code supplied to Google is "centered" in water (related post: [Distance Matrix API: Zip Code 70128 returns zero results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763187/distance-matrix-api-zip-code-70128-returns-zero-results/33763632)) or on an island (such as 02543 : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=47601,%20USA&destinations=02543,%20USA), the status returned is "ZERO_RESULTS".

It is possible to drive to Woods Hole, MA 02543 though. For example 266 Woods Hole Road, Woods Hole, MA 02543. The address of the Woods Hold Oceanographic Institution.

Since a US postal code is not a specific location, I'm not looking for exact distance... so "nearby" would be okay for quoting purposes. Any suggestions?

Comment: How many locations is it?  Have you tried geocoding them to see if you get results?  It looks like geocoding the zipcode, then reverse geocoding the resulting coordinates might give you a set of results that could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding the failing zipcode, then reverse geocoding the resulting coordinates look like it will give a set of results that could be used.

The results I get from doing that for your example are:

> Boonville, IN 47601, USA to 16-22 Albatross St, Woods Hole, MA 02543, USA: 1,759 km in 16 hours 39 mins
>
> Boonville, IN 47601, USA to 23 Albatross St, Woods Hole, MA 02543, USA: 1,759 km in 16 hours 39 mins
>
> Boonville, IN 47601, USA to 520 Main St, Falmouth, MA 02540, USA: 1,754 km in 16 hours 33 mins

**code snippet (using the Google Maps Javascript API DistanceMatrix Service):**

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
var map;
// https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=47601,%20USA&destinations=02543,%20USA
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: ["47601, USA"],
    destinations: ["02543, USA"],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status) {
    console.log("status=" + status + ", response=" + response);
    if (status != 'OK') {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var originList = response.originAddresses;
      var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
          if (results[j].status != 'OK') {
            alert("result[" + j + "] Error was: " + results[j].status);
            geocoder.geocode({
              'address': destinationList[i]
            }, reverseGeocodeResult);
            break;
          }
          outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
            ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
            results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function reverseGeocodeResult(response, status) {
  if (status == 'OK') {
    geocoder.geocode({
      latLng: response[0].geometry.location
    }, findDistancesToResponses);
  }
}

function findDistancesToResponses(response, status) {
  var destArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    destArr.push(response[i].geometry.location);
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: ["47601, USA"],
    destinations: destArr,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status) {
    var originList = response.originAddresses;
    var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        if (results[j].status != 'OK') {
          alert("result[" + j + "] " + destinationList[j] + " Error was: " + results[j].status);
        }
        outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
          ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
          results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
      }
    }
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```